# jQuery Function to point to two separate divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the below sample code that isn't working. The user has to be able to hover over "Div 1" and/or "Div2" and a red border appear all the way around it on both (so around Div 1 AND Div 2). In my complex code within a WordPress theme, the elements cannot be nested, otherwise I could use simple CSS to get that accomplished.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    </head>    

<body>
    <div class="attachment-shop_catalog">Div 1</div>
    <div class="title-wrapper">Div 2</div>
</body>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.attachment-shop_catalog .title-wrapper').hover(function() {
   $(this).css('border', '1px solid red');
   },function() {
   $(this).css('border', '0');
   });
});

</script>

</html>
```

CSS (external stylesheet):

```
.attachment-shop_catalog {
    background-color: grey;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-bottom: none;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
    width: 80px;
 }

.title-wrapper {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 40px 20px 40px 20px;
    width: 80px;
}
```

Here are images of the live site where the red border has to appear, but on both elements all at once, not separate like in these screenshots)

[image: Bottom Border Image 1]
[image: Top Border Image 2]

Any help to fix this code will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in Advance! :)

Comment: In the real HTML, is every `.attachment-shop_catalog` div an adjacent sibling to its corresponding `.title-wrapper` div, exactly as you have shown in the question?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.attachment-shop_catalog, .title-wrapper').hover(function() {
   $('.attachment-shop_catalog, .title-wrapper').css('border', '1px solid red');
   },function() {
   $('.attachment-shop_catalog, .title-wrapper').css('border', '0');
   });
});
```

Try this. the selector selects both divs to place/remove border now.

Comment: this doesn't work in my ide. could you show this in a fiddle?

Comment: Why use an external codepen instead of a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) right here?

Answer (score 0):

For binding the handler, you need to use comma to select either element. Space in a selector means that the second class must be a descendant of the first.

And if you want to put a single box around both DIVs, not each DIV by itself, you need to wrap them in another DIV.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.attachment-shop_catalog, .title-wrapper').hover(function() {
    $(this).closest(".container").css('border', '1px solid red');
  }, function() {
    $(this).closest(".container").css('border', '0');
  });
});
```

```css
.attachment-shop_catalog {
    background-color: grey;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-bottom: none;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
    width: 80px;
 }

.title-wrapper {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 40px 20px 40px 20px;
    width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="attachment-shop_catalog">Div 1</div>
  <div class="title-wrapper">Div 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for this answer. Looks like this may work. However, my html is in a very complex WordPress theme. I wouldn't even know how to begin manipulating that html to nest those div's. Is there no way with jQuery to get that accomplished without messing with the html?

Comment: I also think there's something wrong with the syntax in this jQuery. I cannot see what's going on. Im new to this.

Comment: @bay_bay, given the nature of the rendered HTML, it's likely your div-pairs are already in containers ... maybe together with other stuff.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Thanks! My IDE throws a bunch of errors regarding my syntax too... this can't be this difficult :)

Comment: No, it's not difficult. The funadmental requirement is that something somewhere associates your pairs of divs together.

Comment: @bay_bay If there's no container in the HTML, you could use jQuery's `.wrapAll()` method to put a wrapper around them on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

Assumption: The DOM is structured such that `$('.attachment-shop_catalog')` and `$('.title_wrapper')` are congruent (ie. both elements of the same index form a pair), regardless of the physical juxtapositions of pairs with respect to each other.

If this assumption holds, then it seems reasonable that it will hold in the long-term (ie. that it will survive detailed changes to WordPress's DOM content/structure), and you can write your javascript as follows :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var pair = '_hover_binding_'; // a unique, arbitrary string

    // First form a 2-way binding between the two elements of each pair ...
    $('.attachment-shop_catalog').forEach(function() {
        // 1. make a jq object containing `this` and its partner, forming a "pair".
        var $pair = $('.title-wrapper').eq($('.attachment-shop_catalog').index(this)).add(this);
        // 2. bind $pair to both members of the pair.
        $pair.data(pair, $pair);
    })
    // ... then attach hover handlers that act on both members of each pair (self and partner).
    .add('.title-wrapper').hover(function() {
        $(this).data(pair).css('border', '1px solid red');
    }, function() {
        $(this).data(pair).css('border', '0');
    });
});
```

With help from the comments, the overall process should be pretty simple to follow, though it does require a solid understanding of jQuery basics.

And as it turns out, the original assumption is not fundamental to this approach. Any reliable pairing rule at step 1, `var $pair = ...`, will give you a workable solution.